# getFilesDir() returning null

Tags: android

GetFilesDir() is returning null, which is completely bizarre. What's worse, is my code is...painfully simple:

```
public class main extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    File f = this.getFilesDir();
    f.getAbsolutePath();

    tempClicked((ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tempToggle));
}
```

This will crash on f.getAbsolutePath(). It's currently running in the emulator emulating a 2.3.3 system at 1024x600.

Google returns nothing on this...so why on earth is this happening? And how do I fix it?!

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:: SOLVED!**

Well, somewhat...

I think it turned out to be an emulator error. I changed the skin of the emulator to WXVGA, and that then allowed it to write the files correctly. And when I then changed the resolution back to 1024x600 it kept working correctly.

So, if anyone has a similar error, I suggest you play around with the emulator until you find a way past the bug.

Comment: This is strange! On both physical devices and emulators I receive a string such as "/data/data/com.example.myapp/files" when calling Context.getFilesDir(). I even tried to remove my SD card despite the fact it should be independant. Same result. That's actually puzzling.

Comment: @Shlublu The reason you get the same string is that the system has no concept of your SDcard, only internal/external storage.

Comment: I just ran into this bug. It's ridiculous. Changing the emulator skin back and forth fixed it for me as well. Crap like this is why I hate using the emulators.

Comment: Changing the skin didn't work for me, but I checked the "Wipe user data" checkbox when running the emulator, and that fixed it. BTW I don't like the "too localized" closing. So what? It helped several people.

Comment: happened with me too. I checked in debugger path to data folder (property of `Context` instance), it was something `/data/data/<package.name>` and the folder was missing on file system (checked in `adb shell`). Next time the app was deployed to device (switched from debug to regular run in AS) everything worked ok, and the folder appeared on FS. So it appears to be an app installation issue

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this before f.getAbsolutePath():

```
File f = new File(this.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/");
f.mkdirs();
```

Comment: It turned out to be an emulator error. I played around with the emulator skin and density and the code, without changing it, suddenly sprang to life. If I ran your code while the emulator was still buggy, it would have tried to make the foldder /null/ which wouldn't have worked anyway...

Comment: man, getFilesDir() itself returning null, so how will it be going to work !!