# GetfileDir() Application class return NULL

Tags: android

Below code prints NULL when trying to get  file directory path.kindly let me know what i am doing wrong?

```
public class MyApp extends Application 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.e("gf", "onCreate: "+getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

depends on what you are trying to do

as described in the docs the [Context.getFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()) shoud only be used to access and maintain relative paths

try to use [Environment.getDataDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getDataDirectory()) , this should also not change if the app is moved to external storage

if it still does not work please provide a few more informations about your android phone / simulator and your environment

Answer (score 0):

That code works for me. You might have an incorrect emulator setting (as discussed here [getFilesDir() returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779833/getfilesdir-returning-null)).

From the answer in the question:

> I think it turned out to be an emulator error. I changed the skin of the emulator to WXVGA, and that then allowed it to write the files correctly. And when I then changed the resolution back to 1024x600 it kept working correctly.
>
> So, if anyone has a similar error, I suggest you play around with the emulator until you find a way past the bug.

The linked question was answered in the question post, which is why I can't mark this as a duplicate of it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my bad, With hectic schedule, I missed defining the application class in manifest file. Any way thanks for all of your sug